# Creating a graph based on users choice in 'Dash'

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash, interactive

I am very new to python and 'Dash' - I am looking for a way in which I can plot a graph from the data that is chosen.

The following is my code, but for some reason I'm returning only a blank graph after an option has been chosen?

I think that the issue occurs around the 'Def interactive graphs' part.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import time
from collections import deque
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import random
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("d5.csv").tail(10) 

from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout=html.Div([
    html.H1("Graph Analysis"),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='graph-choice',
                 options=[{'label':'Room 1 Temperature', 'value':'R1Temp'},
                          {'label':'Room 2 Temperature', 'value':'R2Temp'},
                          {'label':'Room 3 Temperature', 'value':'R3Temp'}],
                          
                 value='R1Temp'
                 ),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', figure={}
              )
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='graph-choice', component_property='value')
)

def interactive_graphs(selected_value):
    
    if selected_value == 'R1Temp':
        fig_line = px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R1Temp')

    else if selected_value == 'R2Temp':
        fig_line = px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R1Temp')


    else:
        fig_line = px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R3Temp')
        


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Please post a link to the data to make the example runnable (or add dummy data).

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in you callback. You should the return the figure, i.e. your callback should be something like,

```
@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), Input('graph-choice', 'value'))
def interactive_graphs(selected_value):
    if selected_value == 'R1Temp':
        return px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R1Temp')
    if selected_value == 'R2Temp':
        return px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R1Temp')
    return px.line(data_frame=df, x='Time', y='R3Temp')
```